# Apache Camel Scheduler delay not respected while parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, delay, scheduler

On a *Spring Boot* (2.3.0.RELEASE) application using *Apache Camel* (3.6.0), I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with the *scheduler* component in parallel mode; in particular, I want to create a route which executes a given logic every *n* seconds.
To do so, I've written the following example:

```
@Component
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("scheduler:testRoute?delay=2000")
      .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Test route begin")
      .setBody(this::generateRandomBody)
      .split(body())
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(this::consumeElement)
      .end()
      .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Test route end");
}

private List<Integer> generateRandomBody(Exchange exchange) {
  return IntStream.range(0, random(20)).boxed().collect(toList());
}

private void consumeElement(Exchange exchange) throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.sleep(random(1000));
}

private int random(int max) {
  return new Random().nextInt(max) + 1;
}
```

With the *scheduler.delay* parameter set to 2000 I would expect the *next poll* to be triggered after 2 seconds after **the end** of the current one; however, that's true only by disabling the parallel processing.

In fact, here's an example of output with parallel processing:

```
09:02:56.859    Test route begin
09:02:58.086    Test route end

09:02:58.868    Test route begin
09:02:59.266    Test route end

09:03:00.870    Test route begin
09:03:01.654    Test route end

09:03:02.871    Test route begin
09:03:04.028    Test route end

09:03:04.873    Test route begin
```

and here's an example of output without parallel processing:

```
09:08:01.666    Test route begin
09:08:11.290    Test route end

09:08:13.292    Test route begin
09:08:21.707    Test route end

09:08:23.709    Test route begin
09:08:26.161    Test route end

09:08:28.162    Test route begin
09:08:37.761    Test route end

09:08:39.763    Test route begin
```

As you can see, while parallel processing, the delay is not respected, since the *next poll* time is calculated in respect to the current poll start; on the other hand, without parallel processing, the *next poll* time is approximately 2 seconds after the current poll end.

This seems a bit strange, since the parallel processing documentation states:

> If enabled then processing each splitted messages occurs concurrently. Note the caller thread will still wait until all messages has been fully processed, before it continues. Its only processing the sub messages from the splitter which happens concurrently.

What am I missing here? How can I process messages in parallel and trigger the next poll after the actual route completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Camel 3 the EIPs have been overhauled to be reactive and as such the splitter allows the scheduler thread to complete sooner and can therefore honour the delay of 2 seconds.

If you want the scheduled to wait until the entire exchange is complete (regardless how its processed by different threads), then you need to configure it to be synchronous. Even for Camel 2.

```
 from("scheduler:testRoute?delay=2000&synchronous=true")
```

Comment: And now it's perfectly working! I'm not sure what's more awesome: your product or your incredibly prompt replies :-) Thanks a lot